# How to pass domain as a context in odoo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I have a domain like this `["&",["customer","=",True],["type","=","contact"]]` and 
have context also like this `{"lang":"en_US","tz":"Europe/Brussels","uid":2,"allowed_company_ids":[1],"params":{"action":157,"cids":1,"menu_id":112,"model":"crm.lead","view_type":"kanban"},"default_type":"opportunity","search_default_assigned_to_me":1}`

Now, What I want to do is when I edit the domain and if it contains '&' then our context will be the previous one with the new domain(means that context will look like `{"lang":"en_US","tz":"Europe/Brussels","uid":2,"allowed_company_ids":[1],"params":{"action":157,"cids":1,"menu_id":112,"model":"crm.lead","view_type":"kanban"},"default_type":"opportunity","search_default_assigned_to_me":1}, "default_customer": True, "default_type":"contact")` but if it contains '|' then our context will be previous one (means that now the context will look like `{"lang":"en_US","tz":"Europe/Brussels","uid":2,"allowed_company_ids":[1],"params":{"action":157,"cids":1,"menu_id":112,"model":"crm.lead","view_type":"kanban"},"default_type":"opportunity","search_default_assigned_to_me":1}`).

Can anyone suggest how to do this...

Comment: What?!! where do you want to change this XML, Py , in method in XML action .....????

Comment: In JS side that what I think when performing change operation on the domain, then we can identify by _.contains(input.val(),'&') but it give list then how to convert it in to dictionary to insert in the context.